# Mysql - Select rows which have less than x "child rows"

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a table like this:

```
planet_id | planet_name

1         | Test planet
2         | Test planet 2
```

I got a second table like this

```
area_id   | area_name   | planet_id
1         | test_area   | 1
```

I need a select query to only select planets which have less than 5 areas. How do I do that?

Comment: Should planets that have *no areas* be included as well?

Comment: Yes, planets without areas should also be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can group by planets joined with areas and group by the planets. you can then use having to filter

```
select one.planet_id, one.planet_name
from first_table one
join second_table two
on (one.planet_id = two.planet_id)
group by one.planet_id, one.planet_id
having count(two.area_id) < 5
```

Comment: `left join` would suit better since planets with 0 areas should be returned too (based on the OP's clarification in the comments to the question).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andriy, I use Bretts statement with a left join now and it works perfectly.